# Вывод всей строки в messagebox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, datagridview

Не могу понять как в MessageBox вывести всю строку которая заполнена значениями.
В строке есть 6 колонок. Необходимо в выделенной строке пройтись по ячейкам и вывести значения.

Я вроде как понимаю что нужно пройтись for each'ем но не соображаю как его грамотно составить.

Comment: Шесть раз подряд MessageBox? Или один в котором шесть значений?

Comment: не, в один messageBox засунуть 6 переменных. Но это без проблем, тут я знаю как сделать)
Но я уже решил задачку, спасибо)

Comment: Ну и отлично :) Обновите свой ответ и отметьте его как решение, вдруг другим пригодится.

Comment: Обязательно помечу как ответ, и немного доработаю, только через два дня, правила стаковерфлоу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Я взял каждую отдельную ячейку выбранной строки. Благо их количество позволяет так поступить

```
id = dataGridView1->CurrentRow->Cells[0]->Value->ToString();
MessageBox::Show(id);
```